# Flex 3 Localization: Removing a Locale

Tags: apache-flex, localization

Although I'm still poking around in the docs and online, I figured I'd ask this one here, for future folks who run into it.

Using copylocale for localization, I made a typo (e.g., "en_FR" instead of "fr_FR") and mistakenly created a locale I don't want.  What's the proper way to remove it?  Is it enough to simply delete it from my framework directory, or is there a helper app somewhere that handles the cleanup if there's more to it than that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to simply delete it from the locale directory.  The copylocale just creates a copy, nothing more.  Just nuke it and you should be good to go.  More information here:

http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flex_3:Feature_Introductions:_Runtime_Localization